# iphone App crashing After FbRequest method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook

I have made an iPhone App which has a "loginwithFacebook" button , the login procedure is working fine . but App crashes after  passing through the FBRequest method "**`- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result` "** and **"`- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` "** .

I tried to put some break point in these methods. Then , I was amaized to see that App is working After some delay with that i made putting the break points.

Is it something related to loading the connection or Delay of the content loading from 
Fbrequest method ???

please help me ..

Comment: can you post some code? inside you didLoad method

Comment: the error I'm getting is something related to connection "[NSNull lowercaseString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2124ce8"

Comment: hey i don't have enough points to post sample code dear!

Comment: the problem could be in didLoad method, try to get the classname of result,   code something like NSLog(@"result class == %@", NSStringFromClass([result class]));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[NSNull lowercaseString]** which means your one string is null and you are trying to apply lowercaseString method to that string. keep a null check condition before this method call or  you can check why this string is null.

Comment: hey my App is already in the App store , it is working fine in iPhone 4 and iPhone 3GS .....it was working in my simulator ...i don't know what happened suddenly????...............

Comment: Ok, did u use graph api for Facebook?

Comment: Enable the NSZombieEnable to YES and u will be able to check the exact point where the crash happens.

Comment: how to enable zombie in iOS 4.3

Comment: yes, i used graph API to get the  users details -  NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   
    [[delegate facebook] requestWithMethodName:@"fql.query"
                                     andParams:params
                                 andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                                   andDelegate:self];

Comment: you can enable NSZombieEnable flag from below path:

XCode -> Product Menu -> Edit Scheme -> add NSZombieEnable Set Yes in Environment variables

Run the program. and don't forget to remove NSZombieEnable while creating appstore build

Comment: madam,i found the  real issue . I cannot fetch my Facebook email address from the API call which i was getting earlier ,did Facebook change anything regarding the fetching of user details, because the email address string is Null now,which was working fine earlier. But the confusing thing is , in my iPhone 3gs, still we can get the email Address .

Comment: i commented the section where email is needed and now,the App is working fine .My friend told that Facebook have changed the format of fetching the user details i.e. Earlier we use to get the users first name, Last name, picture url and email address.But now, except the email address everything else can be fetched when we request for the user details....is it true ??

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to the access token of Facebook. because when u log in with Facebook, you will get one access token, and that token is used everywhere, so try to check the access token as its not nil. and this is just my assumption but will request you to keep your code where the crash happened. else post the crash reason from console.

Comment: [NSNull lowercaseString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2124ce8